# Using race from cats-effect prevents app from exiting

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect

I've got simple cats-effect app, which download site from the URL given as argument. During downloading app is supposed to display "loading bar" by writting dots (`.`) to console. I implemented it by doing *race* of two *IOs* one for downloading another for displaying dots.

This is whole app on [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/WjSXYszvTae6bFt9SRVmLA).

The most important part is here:

```scala
def loader(): IO[Unit] = for {
      _ <- console.putStr(".")
      _ <- timer.sleep(Duration(50, MILLISECONDS)) *> loader()
    } yield {}


  def download(url: String): IO[String] = IO.delay(Source.fromURL(url)).map(_.mkString)

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[Unit] = {

    args.headOption match {
      case Some(url) =>
        for {
          content <- IO.race(download(url), loader()).map(_.left.get)
          _ <- console.putStrLn() *> console.putStrLn(s"Downloaded site from $url. Size of downloaded content is ${content.length}.")
        } yield {}

      case None => console.putStrLn("Pass url as argument.")
    }
  }
```

Everything works as I expected, when I run it, I get:

> ..............
>   Downloaded site from https://www.scala-lang.org. Size of downloaded content is 47738.

Only problem is that app never exits.

As far as I checked *loader IO* gets cancelled correctly. I can even add something like this:

```
urlLoader.run(args) *> console.putStrLn("???") *> IO(ExitCode.Success)
```

And `???` gets displayed.

Also when I remove *race*, then app exits correctly.

So my question how can I fix this and make my app exit at the end?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `Timer` provided by `IOApp`? At a glance it looks like the problem is that you're not shutting down your scheduler, which you wouldn't have to worry about if you were using the built-in timer.

Comment: I missed that `IOApp` already profides `Timer`.  I took my implementation from [there](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/timer.html). Not it works like charm, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow up on my comment above: the problem is that your `ScheduledExecutorService` has threads running that prevent the JVM from exiting, even though your timer's tasks have been cancelled. There are several ways you could resolve this:

- Add a `IO(ses.shutdown())` before `IO(ExitCode.Success)`.
- Call `newScheduledThreadPool` with a thread factory that daemonizes its threads.
- Use the `timer: Timer` that you get for free inside `IOApp`.

The last of these is almost definitely the right choice—using the timer (and `ContextShift`) provided by `IOApp` will give you reasonable defaults for this and other behaviors.

Answer (score 0):

You may also prevent an early JVM exit using Scala futures with a code like this:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
    
Await.ready(Future.never, Duration.Inf)
```